# Consuming REST full service POST c#

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

I have created many rest end points that are basically get request.
But now I have to create a post request.
Here is my OperationContract

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            UriTemplate = "Product/Save",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        ServiceResult Save(ProductInfo request);
```

Can any one say how can I cosume this POST request in a console applicatiobn?

I refered [Consuming REST Service pb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251489/consuming-rest-service-pb)

but HttpWebRequest is marked as obselate in  my .net frame work 4.0/visual sudio 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use HttpClient instead of HttpWebRequest
```

Comment: I dont have PostAsJsonAsync  on my  HttpClient object

Comment: adde newton soft for this

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client this link helped me

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with the HttpListener Class (to get requests):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.net.httplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

and HttpListenerResponse (to send responses):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.net.httplistenerresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client link helped me